# MessageBox not showing when "Unhandled Exception" triggers in winforms

Tags: winforms, exception, handler, messagebox

so I was trying to add "`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`" handler to my application and it worked OK if I log the error to a text file. but when I try to use a MessageBox it never pops. is it another bug in .Net? any ideas?

here is my code sample:

```
   AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);

   Application.EnableVisualStyles();
   Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
   Application.Run(new Form1());
```

and here is my handler method:

```
static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException (object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
       Exception ex = (Exception)e.ExceptionObject;

       MessageBox.Show("Whoops! Please contact the developers with "
                   + "the following information:\r\n\r\n" + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace,
                   "Fatal Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);

    }
    finally
    {
       Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I've tried all of the possible options but I still can't see the MessageBox. Now the problem is when I run it from Visual C# (debug mode) it perfectly shows the box. but when I run the application directly from the debug/release folders it doesn't shows the MessageBox and the Application keeps running like there is no error is happening...

Comment: i have no problem with your code, all works fine.... (i have tryed to compile with .net 2.0 and 4.0, both works)

Comment: @punker76 - hmm that's weird. are you on 64-bit machine?

Comment: i compiled as Debug/Release x86 on 64bit machine Win7 and VS2010

Comment: @punker76 - I've updated the question with more information... the messagebox shows ok when I run it from VC# debug mode. but when I run it directly from the debug folder (double clicking the exe) the message box never pops up..

Comment: "the function is actually being executed from a new Thread".  That's a problem.  MessageBox is a dialog and like any dialog it needs an owner window to be on top of.  Winforms cannot find such an owner for code that runs on a worker thread.  The message box is still displayed, but good odds that it appears underneath the main window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this example works for me in debug mode and release mode with vs2010 or not:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinFormsStackOverflowSpielWiese
{
  internal static class Program
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    private static void Main() {
      System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException += new System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);
      System.Windows.Forms.Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
      AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);

      Application.EnableVisualStyles();
      Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
      Application.Run(new Form1());
    }

    private static void Application_ThreadException(object sender, System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventArgs e) {
      try {
        var exception = e.Exception != null ? e.Exception.Message + e.Exception.StackTrace : string.Empty;
        MessageBox.Show("Whoops! Please contact the developers with the following information:\r\n\r\n" + exception,
                        "Fatal Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
      }
      finally {
        Application.Exit();
      }
    }

    private static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) {
      try {
        var exception = e.ExceptionObject is Exception ? ((Exception)e.ExceptionObject).Message + ((Exception)e.ExceptionObject).StackTrace : string.Empty;
        MessageBox.Show("Whoops! Please contact the developers with the following information:\r\n\r\n" + exception,
                        "Fatal Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
      }
      finally {
        Application.Exit();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

code for the form

**EDIT** now with a timer, with the same result....

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinFormsStackOverflowSpielWiese
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    private System.Threading.Timer myTimer;

    public Form1() {
      this.InitializeComponent();

      this.myTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(state =>
                                                  {
                                                    var i = 0;
                                                    var s = 100 / i;
                                                  }
                                                , null, 5000, 5000);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this is partially worked. but when the exception occurs on different location it just never pops out... I'm using a timer and there is a function runs every 3 seconds from that timer. the function is actually being executed from a new Thread. now I really don't know what's causing this and why is that happening. but I guess its a bigger problem than it seems... thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

The case might be because `Unhandled` `Exceptions` cause the application to terminate silently and `UnhandledExceptionEventHandler` handles non-UI thread exceptions.

See [Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.setunhandledexceptionmode.aspx) Method, [AppDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) Event and [Application.ThreadException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx) Event

**EDIT:**
Try setting `Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode` as per first link:

```
Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException); //add this line

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);    
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

Comment: Nope that's not the case. I've tried all of the possible options but I still can't see the MessageBox. Now the problem is when I run it from Visual C# (debug mode) it perfectly shows the box. but when I run the application directly from the debug/release folders it never shows the MessageBox...

Comment: @RobinVanPersi try using Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode method before subscribing to events..see the edit.

Comment: same thing... nothing changed.. please try to run the produced application directly from the debug folder..

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party but no workable solution is shown here. I added

Application.DoEvents();

Just before the message box and the MessageBox now shows.

Hope this helps somebody out.